# Can't find where netbeans 8.1 stores the path to the maven local repository (.m2)

Tags: java, maven, path, configuration, netbeans-8.1

I moved the local repository and changed it in the settings.xml in the .m2 but netbeans keeps looking for the previous location.
I am having some difficulties to find where netbeans stores the path to the maven local repository.

In another question, I found the following answer :
"In Project Explorer window within Netbeans you will find services tab.
Goto: services->maven repositories->local->right click->properties
You will get the Local Repository path which netbeans is using."
I found the path used. But that, I already knew.

If it can be of any help, here's my research so far :
I checked every file I could think of (build.properties, pom.xml, config files in the netbeans install folder or in the User_Home/appData/netbeans)... netbeans keeps searching for the older path.

I edited the settings.xml in maven_home (bundled so in netbeans/java/maven..) by giving the new path in the <localRepository> section without success.

Any idea in which file this path could be stored? Could it be in the netBeans cache?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in `~/.netbeans/9.0/config/Preferences/org/openide/filesystems/nb.properties`. Maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I already checked every .properties files I could find.
Weird enough, I can't find a .netbeans, except in my D: partition but it only contains a .superId
I found a similar path in user-home/appData/roaming/netBeans/8.1/config/Preferences/org/openide/filesystems/nb.properties ... which contains a single row for the export.optionsChooserPanel.

If it's of any help, my laptop runs with win10 enterprise (x64) and has two partitions C: and D: 
At first, .m2 was in my D: partition but decided with a coworker to use a similar config and then placed it in my user-home.